# Python asyncio task do not start

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

I'm trying to understand python asyncio lib, but it's a pain and each time I think i know how the code will behave, something suprises me.

I have the following code:

```
async def a():
    while True:
        task = asyncio.current_task()  # asyncio.Task.current_task()
        print(task.name)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def main():
    tasks = []

    for i in range(10):
        c = a()
        task = asyncio.create_task(c)
        task.name = "task nr {}".format(i)
        tasks.append(task)

    for task in tasks:
        await task

asyncio.run(main())
```

Would result with the following output as suspected:

```
task nr 0
task nr 1
task nr 2
task nr 3
task nr 4
task nr 5
task nr 6
task nr 7
task nr 8
task nr 9
```

and so on.
On the other hand I have a code

```
async def a():
    while True:
        task = asyncio.current_task()  # asyncio.Task.current_task()
        print(task.name)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def main():

    for i in range(10):
        c = a()
        task = asyncio.create_task(c)
        task.name = "task nr {}".format(i)
        await task

asyncio.run(main())
```

This time it outputs just "task nr 0".

In the first one creates 10 tasks and then starst all of them. The second one merges those two loops - why it affects behaviour of the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The second one merges those two loops - why it affects behaviour of the program?

Because your first code runs [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) for all ten coroutines before getting to an `await`.

Since `create_task` schedules the execution of the coroutine, in the first example all ten coroutines are happily executing in parallel while you are awaiting the first one (which, as the other answer [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53365844/1600898), will never complete because the coroutines are infinite). In the second loop you are only executing *one* `create_task` before the infinite await, so you only get one coroutine running.

If you are familiar with threads, perhaps the following analogy will help: You can think of `create_task` as spawning a thread, and `await` as joining it. In the first example you've spawned ten of them, and in the second only one.

Answer (score 2):

Your `a()` is an infinite coroutine. The process of awaiting it will **never** complete. Meaning that in your second snippet the `for` loop will never enter next iteration. It is basically "blocked" forever on `await task`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be true also in the first code snippet for the second `for`-loop?

Comment: @MichaelButscher it is, yes. But in the first code await runs **after** all tasks are already created.

Comment: I should have read the docs, `create_task` already runs the task, thanks.